# What to answer to a recruiter when I'm not currently interested in a new job

Tags: recruitment, networking

I'm currently employed and I'm not seeking to change jobs at this time. Occasionally, I'm contacted by recruiters with offers that would be a good match for me, if I were looking for a job (targeted, even sometimes personalized.).

Given that, I've decided that I want to answer, but I'm unsure how to word my response. What is one expected to say in this case? Are there any cliche phrases that I should avoid?

Comment: The first sentence of your post seems perfectly appropriate to me.

Comment: Keep in mind in almost 99.99% of cases, these emails are automatically generated. Contacting them will result in you becoming "active" and thus you'd notice an even more increase in these sudden "offers." Unless you're being recruited by an actual company and not a consultant agency, then I'd just ignore these emails.

Answer (score 16):

> Given that, I've decided that I want to answer, but I'm unsure how to
>   word my response. What is one expected to say in this case?

In a similar situation, I always say something like "Thank you for your interest, but at this time I'm not seeking to change jobs."

That's simple but polite. It indicates that you aren't interested now. And it doesn't preclude a callback at some point in the future.

Answer (score 6):

It is a good thing to let the recruiter know that you are not looking for job change, politely and with gratitude.

I would reply with something like this in such situations -

> Thank you for considering me for the opportunity, but right now I am not
>   looking for job change.

Comment: Don't forget to add "Stay in touch" :)